# Clear ZMQ queue after message has been received

Tags: c, perl, zeromq

I'm trying to do IPC between one single sender and one single receiver using ZMQ. My sender is in perl and my receiver is in C. I want my receiver to be constantly listening to messages the sender sends to the queue, therefore I have a while loop running the zmq_recv() function. The problem, however, is that the receiver keeps reading the same message infinitely. I want the receiver to read the message only once and then have the queue cleared. Here is my very basic setup:

Perl (sender):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use ZMQ::FFI qw(ZMQ_REQ);

my $endpoint = "ipc://zmq-ffi-1";
my $ctx      = ZMQ::FFI->new();

my $p = $ctx->socket(ZMQ_REQ);
$p->connect($endpoint);

$p->send('Hello');
sleep(5);
```

C (receiver):

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *replier = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind(replier, "ipc://zmq-ffi-1");
    assert(rc == 0);

    char buffer[10];
    while(1) {
        zmq_recv(replier, buffer, 10, 0); // infinitely receives "Hello"
        // clear the queue here if possible 
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }

    zmq_close(replier);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
    return 0;
}
```

See above for details

Comment: You should check the return values of the zmq functions for errors...

Comment: And read up on `ZMP_REP` and think about if your code is using it correctly.

Comment: *The problem, however, is that the receiver keeps reading the same message infinitely* that shouldn't happen with `ZMQ_REP`. Like Shawn said, please check that return value of `zmq_recv`, I bet it's returning -1.

Comment: And, strictly speaking, it'd be better to empty the buffer too. Set all of buffer[] = 0; You're relying on buffer being initialised to all zero, but it's implementation dependent as written (I think). There's nothing in particular about zmq_recv() that says "C style null terminated string", so the necessary terminating null may not be sent by the sending app and therefore may not be present in buffer after the call to zmq_recv(). For example, try sending "HelloHello", which would not overflow buffer, but would not have a 0 on the end.